# Is there a way to access variables 'to the left' and 'to the right' of a vector using indexes?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::sort;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Point {
 public:
  int x, y;
  Point() : x(0), y(0){};
  Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){};
};

bool compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
  int p1_gap = p1.x + p1.y;
  int p2_gap = p2.x + p2.y;
  return p1_gap < p2_gap;
}

Point closestCoin(Point yourPos, vector<Point> coinPositions) {
  Point res;
  coinPositions.push_back(yourPos);
  Point *p = (&yourPos);
  sort(coinPositions.begin(), coinPositions.end(), compare);
  // The reason I am doing this approach is because I want to be able to take
  // position of YourPos, and compare it with the positions to the left and to
  // right of it. In my understanding, this will allow for o(nlogn) time, which
  // is better than o(n). I tried to find a way to do this without using
  // std::find(), as that would defeat the purpose of this approach.
  return res;
}
```

The point of the function closestCoin() is to find the closest coin, whos positions are stored in a vector of coinPositions, to your position. The reason I went with this attempt was because instead of comparing all the positions of the coins to our position, we could just throw our position in a vector, sort it, and would only have to compare two positions. However, I am fully stumped on how to access essentially what would be the points that are closest to our position.

Comment: If you have an index `i` to an element in a vector, then you can access the previous element using the index `i - 1`, and the next element using `i + 1`. But beware of the special cases when `i` is an index to the first or last elements of the vector. For vectors this subtraction and addition also works for iterators.

Comment: But, in this case, in order to determine the index/iterator of the pushed copy of `yourPos` in the sorted vector, you have to search the vector for it, which kind of defeats the purpose of avoiding `std::find()` in the first place.

Comment: *"this will allow for o(nlogn) time, which is better than o(n)"* -- no, linear time, O(n), is better than linear times logarithmic, O(n lg n). Just pick a big number and compare: 1000 < 1000 * lg(1000), which is almost 10,000.

Comment: Note that the line `Point *p = (&yourPos);` does nothing to help your goal, as it stores the address of the function parameter, not of an element of your vector.

Comment: Note that your comparison makes for example (0,10), (3,7), (5,5), and (8,2) equivalent (i.e. they are "the same" according to your ordering). This is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Use a `std::set`. You get an iterator directly from `emplace()` or from `find()`. Then move that iterator back and forth (checking for bounds, of course) to get the neighboring positions. Use a comparator that gets the ordering right.